# How do I check if a value-event observer already has been attached to a Firebase node?

Tags: swift, firebase

My problem is that I need to find out if a .value observer already has been attached to a certain node in Firebase Realtime Database. Right now I´m doing the following steps:

1. Making a query on the node rootReference.advertisementsAttending.userId, from which I get a dictionary of key-value pairs [advertisementId: advertisementTimestamp] for all advertisements (in fact advertisementIds) a certain user attends.
2. I loop the obtained dictionary and for each advertisementId, I attach a value event observer at the node rootReference.advertisements.advertisementId such that I get all the data of the advertisement.
3. I put the advertisements in an dictionary (advertisementsDictionary) which I later user to populate a collectionView

Everything works just fine. However, when the user is booking a new advertisement (say from another device) the initial query will get triggered (step 1.). The loop (2.) will then be triggered again. When this happens, I only want to attach a .value event observer if none already exist at rootReference.advertisements.advertisementId in order to avoid multiple observers on the same node.

I´ve tried to accomplish this by saving reference-handle pairs in a dictionary [reference: handle] and before attaching an observer, I check if the dictionary has a key equal to the reference. If not, I attach the observer and at the same time add a key-value pair to the dictionary observerDictionary[reference] = handle.

This does however not seem to work. When the loop is triggered a second time, I attach observers to all advertisements, even those that have observers from before.

So my question is: Is there another way to check if an observer already is attached to a certain node such that I avoid adding multiple listeners?

My code is as follows:

```
rootReference.child("advertisementsAttending").child(currentUser.userId).queryOrderedByValue().observe(.value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
    for keyValuePair in dataSnapshot.children {
        let childSnapshot = keyValuePair as! DataSnapshot
        let advertisementId = childSnapshot.key
        let advertisementReference = rootReference.child("advertisements").child(advertisementId)
        let advertisementReferenceHandle: UInt!

        // Check if observer already is attached to advertisementReference
        if observerDictionary[advertisementReference] == nil {
            advertisementReferenceHandle = advertisementReference.observe(.value, with: { (advertisementSnapshot) in
                let advertisement = Advertisement()
                advertisement.populateAdvertisementFromSnapshot(snapshot: advertisementSnapshot)
                advertisementsDictionary[advertisement.advertisementId] = advertisement
                // Populating collectionView ...
            })

            // Add key-value pair to observerDictionary
            observerDictionary[advertisementReference] = advertisementReferenceHandle
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Adding and removing observers is fairly straight forward so there is an answer but looking at the code, you may be going down the wrong path in general. It seems like you are adding a lot of observers when you may only need one. Can you expand on your use case a bit? Why are you adding specific observers on specific nodes? Also, you are using .value observer which loads *everything* in the node if *anything* changes. You may want to investigate a more granular solution with .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved events which present only the modified node.